# Logging raw pointer values in Tracepoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio

If there's some sample code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    auto fooPtr = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; // <-- Add a tracepoint here
}
```

and I add a [tracepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-tracepoints?view=vs-2022) on the `cout` line as follows

```
Fooptr is {fooPtr.get()}
```

I get

> Fooptr is Function std::_Ptr_base::get has no address, possibly
> due to compiler optimizations.

which is quite possible(and yes, I'm building a debug version with [`/Od`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/od-disable-debug?view=msvc-170)). So I tried using this in the tracepoint instead

```
Fooptr is {fooPtr._Ptr}
```

which yields

> Fooptr is 0x006473a4 {x=0 }

This is better but I don't really need the `{x = 0}` part in the output. This can get very unwieldy for complex classes with multiple members. Is there a better way to go about this or avoid the information about internal members being logged to the output?

VS Version: 16.9.2 (2019)

EDIT: This does have a solution in the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2022) where the raw value can be logged for numeric values using the `nvo` format specifier. Hence something like:

```
Fooptr is {fooPtr._Ptr, nvo}
```

logs the raw pointer value.

Comment: If you're build a debug build, you should have the flag -O0 (on GCC, not too familiar with MSVC), which disables code optimisation. You should then also have debug symbols.
If you only want the raw addresses, you could use `printf("%p", mySharedPtr.get());`

Comment: I recommend reporting to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem) to optimize this feature.